# Add to Cart button doesn’t add products to cart with Samsung Galaxy Tablet

Tags: magento-1.7, galaxy-tab

Magento product add to cart is not working on Samsung tablet.
I am using magento 1.7.0.2
Its working fine on my PC,
but when I am using it from my tablet, Add to cart not working in tablet.
What can be issue?
Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the Session Cookie Cache Cookie Lifetime
System > Configuration > Web > Session Cookie Cache
Per default it's 3600,
try with increasing it to 33600.
That worked out for me.